# Unable to put values into either string array or string pointers via a function

Tags: c, arrays, string, return, parameter-passing

I have a program in which I have a 200 character string that I split into segments and am trying, without success, to put these segments into either a 2d char array or an array of pointers to strings via a function.  I can successfully do this in main, but when I pass the character string and the 2d char array or pointer array to strings to a function it doesn’t work. When I print the 2d array inside the function it shows everything worked perfectly but when I print the returned array in main it only prints the final value as follows.

A simplified code sample and output is below:

```
void func(char *buffer, char **file_list) 
{  
  /*split buffer into segments*/  
    Strcpy((*file_list + i), segment);  
    Printf(“i = %d file_list = %s \n”,i, (*file_list + i));  /* this prints the segments perfectly*/  
}  

Main()  
{  
   Func(buffer, file_list);  
  For(i=0;i<n;i++)  
     Printf(“i= %d,split lines in main is %s\n”,i,(*file_list +i));  
}
```

The printf output inside “func” is:

```
Segment one  
Segement two  
 ……  
Segment n
```

The printf output from main is:

```
Segment n  
Segment n  
…..  
Segment n
```

---

Please find the function in more detail below.  I’m assuming you don’t need to see the variable declaration list.

Please note that I also tried passing the pointers as references with the view that if buffer was a reference to the original string character array then I would be pointing to that and not temporary strings. But admittedly I don’t know a lot about temporary variables.

```
Void func(char *buffer,  char **file_list)  
{
    newline=strstr(buffer,"\r\n");    
    while (newline != NULL  && (newline-buffer)< READ_SIZE)  
  {  
      temp_var=newline;  
      newline=strstr(newline + 1,"\r\n");  
      if( newline !=NULL )    
      {
          strncpy((*file_list+i),temp_var,(newline-temp_var));  
          printf("i= %d, file_list is %s\n",i, (*file_list+i));  
      }   
   }  
}  

Main()   
{  
    Char *buffer = (char * ) malloc(200*sizeof(char));  
    Char **file_list= blah blah ….  

   /* put 200 char string in buffer*/   

  /*file_list is still empty call func to fill it up*/     

   Func(buffer,file_list);  
   For(i=0;i<n;i++)  
      printf("i= %d, file_list is %s\n",i,(*file_list+i));  
}
```

Print Output from function is:

```
i=0 file list is "segment one"  
i=1 file list is "segment two"  
....  
i=n file list is "segment n"
```

Print Output from main is:

```
i=0 file list is "segment n"  
i=1 file list is "segment n"  
....  
i=n file list is "segment n"
```

Comment: That's no "simplified", that's an invalid program. Please post a snippet that compiles, runs and shows the error.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have added a more detailed piece of code. If you need more please let me know

Comment: I haven't undone my -1. You shouldn't post a program that contains obvious syntax errors.

Comment: Hello I just updated the output I get to try to make it more clear

Comment: What syntax error are you reffering to? This compiles fine on my computer.

Comment: I'm a newbie who is not familiar with computer parlance and so you need to be more explicit with me, what do you mean by "-1" error? PS word kept capitalizing the first letter so please ignore that.

Comment: computer programming 101, don't use Word. Use a text editor. Just copy-paste from your editor into this website so we can copy-paste your code and run it.

Comment: It might be easier if I email you the program. How would I do that? Thank you.

Comment: I'm parsing an online data file which I download in 200 character sized portions, that is why I suggest emailing you the file. I could try instead to make a fake string with mulitple \r\n segments in it, but am not sure how to generate that in a string as I believe if I did something like char *s="blah blah \r\n blah ...." I would not get the desired effect. Thank you

Comment: Thanks anyway but I'd like to close this question since I found that my problem was that I was using the wrong notation in my pointer to pointer chars.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your responses. I found that the problem was not related to returning data from the function in the incorrect way but was due to the fact that I was using the incorrect notation for the pointer to pointer arrays. However, any good references on returning data from functions would be appreciated, as there seems to be conflicting information out there on the web. For example, I don't think you need to declare a pointer to a pointer to pass the pointer by reference. At least by experimenting I found I was able to change pointer array values without passing a pointer to the pointer array to the function in the same way that you pass a normal variable by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are copying only one of your segments and not all of them. Did you intend the `func` call to be from the `for` loop?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes it is in the form of a for loop otherwise I would not be able to print all the file_list[i] variables correctly within the function.  When I try printing file list outside of the function in main it only prints the last value copied over in the way I have indicated above.

Comment: Thanks anyway but I'd like to close this question since I found that my problem was that I was using the wrong notation in my pointer to pointer chars.